# CALCULO DO VALOR DE UMA COLUNA MENOS O VALOR DEBAIXO DA OUTRA COLUNA PYSPARK

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spark

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte cálculo:
[quando a ação for 0, fazer o tempoInicial - tempoFinal do segundo 0 e fazer isso até o fim do dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAJKL.jpg)
já tentei usar o LEAD, mas infelizmente não se encaixa. Alguém teria alguma idéia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Acredito que você possa fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lead

#particionei e ordenei por esse campos, verifique se é o ideal para você
w = Window.partitionBy("Identificador", "nomeTela").orderBy("Identificador","tempoInicial")

df_ans = df.filter(col("acao") ==  0).withColumn("valor_lead", lead(col("tempoFinal")).over(w))
df_ans = df_ans.filter(col("acao") ==  0).withColumn("valor_calculo", col("tempoInicial") - lead(col("tempoFinal")).over(w))
```

Criei duas colunas, a coluna "valor_lead" seria apenas para verificar se o valor que está retornando no lead é o esperado. Na coluna "valor_calculo" é o calculo em si que você citou. Além disso, como você citou que apenas os valores com acao igual a zero interessavam, filtrei por esses valores.
O Dataframe resultante foi o abaixo:

[image: df resultante]

OBS: verifique se o cálculo é realmente tempoInicial menos tempoFinal, pois os valores serão sempre negativos. Caso contrário é apenas inverter no código.

Comment: obrigada, era exatamente isso que eu precisava <3

Comment: Você tem que escolher melhor as perguntas que responde. Não possui o [mcve] presente na pergunta provavelmente e você ganhou 15 pontos mas o sistema provavelmente  irá remover a pergunta pelos problemas que já o expliquei, se isso acontecer você irá perder os 15 pontos.

Comment: Ontem você respondeu uma que foi boa e tanto a pergunta como a resposta sāo compartilhaveis.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Entendo. Vou me atentar mais aos requisitos mínimos.